# Large file support not working on Android

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, g++, large-file-support

I'm trying to build md5deep (http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) for android, but with the default build setup, the assertion that `sizeof(off_t) == 8` fails, indicating (AFAIK) that LFS isn't enabled.  I've tried enabling by adding `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to the gcc and g++ flags, but it still doesn't do the trick.  Adding lines to print the values of _FILE_OFFSET_BITS and sizeof(off_t) shows that the former is indeed 64, but the latter is 4 instead of 8.

Any ideas why?